# Rails respond_to goes to link, but does not load the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On rails 6.0.3.1, I am attempting a simple respond_to statement to notify the user they have successfully interacted with my system. Here is my code:

```
@conversation = Conversation.new(p)
respond_to do |format|
    if @conversation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @conversation, notice: 'Conversation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @conversation }
    else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @conversation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

This code will then input the correct link into the browser, but it does not load the correct page, nor does it print the notice to the screen. The user can then refresh the page to be brought to the correct page, but obviously it should take the user to that page automatically, rather than forcing them to hit the refresh button. Here is an image of what pops up in the in chrome:

[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsnRI.png)

I am having similar problems elsewhere in my code as well. I am a rails newbie. Thanks for the help!